# Cancellable setTimeout based on promise

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, type-definition

The following implementation throws an error (see comment below), how to resolve this?

```
interface PromiseWithAbort extends Promise<unknown> {
  abort: () => void
}

export const pause = (
  ms?: number,
  cb?: (...args: unknown[]) => unknown,
  ...args: unknown[]
): PromiseWithAbort => {
  let timeout

  // Error: Property 'abort' is missing in type 'Promise<unknown>'
  // but required in type 'PromiseWithAbort'.
  const promise: PromiseWithAbort = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    timeout = setTimeout(async () => {
      try {
        resolve(await cb?.(...args))
      } catch (error) {
        reject(error)
      }
    }, ms)
  })

  promise.abort = () => clearTimeout(timeout)

  return promise
}
```

Comment: Beware that this simple approach to cancelable promises won't scale; as soon as you use `then` or `catch` on the promise, you lose the method. It's a bit of a tricky problem, but you might consider passing an optional [`AbortSignal`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortSignal) into `pause`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Could you please elaborate on "as soon as you use then or catch on the promise, you lose the method"? I don't really understand.

Comment: `then`, `catch`, etc. create new promises, usually of the same kind as the promise you call them on. The promise above is a standard `Promise`, so the new promise from `then`/`catch`/`finally` won't have an `abort` method.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Please check the following playground's comments, *ah, sorry, the URL is too long, I'm working on it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder https://tsplay.dev/WoqaLN

Comment: Again, I'm just saying that it doesn't scale. The power of promises is their standard semantics and the way you can compose them together. When you customize instances as you're doing above, you break both of those things. The code there assumes that only the receiver of the initial promise will have reason to abort things, but even just `async function example() { return pause(); } example().abort();` will break. Anyway, happy coding!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you so much for your advice, I'll try implementing the `AbortSignal` approach.

Comment: I forgot to say I'd updated my answer with the example I could have sworn you asked for (but I don't see that comment, so I could be mistaken).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, I did, but I realized I might be taking you too much time on this question, you can update at your convenience, thank you so much!

Comment: :-) I already updated the answer. Happy coding!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the promise you're assigning to `promise` doesn't have an `abort` property, but one is required by the type you've assigned `promise`. One simple way to fix that is to add it before assigning it to `promise`. (This will also let you get rid of the explicit type on `promise`.)

There are a couple of other things as well, see `***` comments:

```typescript
interface PromiseWithAbort extends Promise<unknown> {
    abort: () => void
}

export const pause = (
    ms?: number,
    cb?: (...args: unknown[]) => unknown,
    ...args: unknown[]
): PromiseWithAbort => {
    let timeout: number; // *** Need the type in order to avoid implicit `any`
  
    // *** Add `abort` to the promise before assigning to `promise`
    const promise = Object.assign(
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            timeout = setTimeout(async () => {
                try {
                    resolve(await cb?.(...args));
                } catch (error) {
                    reject(error);
                }
             }, ms); // *** `ms` needs a default value, you're optionally passing `undefined`
        }), {
            abort: () => clearTimeout(timeout)
        }
    );
  
    return promise;
}
```

[On the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-8Vms3t5Idztmw4MgLvAeL1aHo4L0eJLkAcxgByYVnSxDewd3p25yskC4t58JugbbEq0mDRSlOOxQ2VSaHQSBD9BK6tUG1X6sAaPMF+S5uR-YVgHhQEDIAmcCAhkxAA)

That said, using `await` on the promise returned by `cb` (if any) and passing the result into `resolve` is a bit round-about; instead, you can just pass the promise into `resolve`, which will resolve the promise you created to the one returned by `cb` (if any):

```typescript
export const pause = (
    ms?: number,
    cb?: (...args: unknown[]) => unknown,
    ...args: unknown[]
): PromiseWithAbort => {
    let timeout: number;
  
    // *** Add `abort` to the promise before assigning to `promise`
    const promise = Object.assign(
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            timeout = setTimeout(() => { // *** No need for `async`
                try {
                    resolve(cb?.(...args)); // *** No need for `await`, just resolve the promise to `cb`'s promise
                } catch (error) {
                    reject(error);
                }
             }, ms);
        }), {
            abort: () => clearTimeout(timeout)
        }
    );
  
    return promise;
}
```

[On the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApQPYFtgGcIDqwYAFgIIBGGUYyEAHpCACa5qY74A8AriANYgMAdxAA+ZAG8AUMjnI4VGgC5kACgCUyALwSAbhmDNpAX2nSGAB2q0EGELlqW4PfDvWz5WXAH5VIHiwKaAAaTzkECj91ADo4uCgAc1xVPkEREABtAF0tXWQ0oVEw+WQ4mITk1IEirOzpDVV0bDxCYnIlWnyZUoAbCFowYCwIDB4wf0DgqABuT3DkAHpF5AAqdeQyZmZkAANFG13kMAxjkhRLDlbkYJhqFDhcXGBEkFBE49Pdy5b8XYW7A4nFc3NpkAB5CgAKwgCDAFSeLxAagWpRAEGE7F+EDUaigEFwGF6eggIWQ+JhcLyEh6pTpciGIzGXWQ+DAABVhqNxrjqVIlit1qtkAA5U7oiA7O5QPaPACeIAQ-3pKvkYCgcqkqNVKvxhOJOMiPhianKlVwGg0MwFaw2YuQEql1FlwjgxF2ZKhrloeqJJLOFxBKBOe0iuwA5GwfpwINqdcgTMgEHAwAgSOpoJgoFpafHVRTYWA1JnqFa4zqzHm5CYyd4y6qTBoybmdQcVOo+Qh+glOUyeYzuWANOXK-J68gFviwDwoCBkNHWnMTEA)

---

Just for what it's worth, I wouldn't add `abort` to the promise, not least because when you use `.then` or `.catch` on that promise or use it in an `async` function, the promise you get from them won't have the `abort` method. Instead, you might consider accepting an [`AbortSignal`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortSignal).

I'd also remove `cb` and just make `pause` a pure pausing function. `cb` complicates it unnecessarily; you can just use `.then` or `await` and then call `cb` directly in your code.

Here's an example:

```typescript
class CancelledError extends Error {
    constructor(msg = "Operation was cancelled") {
        super(msg);
    }
}

interface PauseOptions {
    signal?: AbortSignal;
    silent?: boolean;
}
export const pause = (
    ms: number,
    {signal, silent = false}: PauseOptions = {}
): Promise<void> => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // Function we'll use if the operation is cancelled
        const cancelled = () => {
            if (!silent) {
                reject(new CancelledError());
            }
        };
        // The actual timer
        const handle = setTimeout(() => {
            if (signal?.aborted) { // It would be rare for this to happen
                cancelled();
            } else {
                resolve();
            }
        }, ms);
        // Handle cancellation
        signal?.addEventListener("abort", () => {
            clearTimeout(handle);
            cancelled();
        });
    });
};
```

[On the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-aB+Qh0+mcgT+sAKJQIBOykWG3mS20aliuYi7Jnq-usWHwqHmscDn2uNaiad27oACUDwa7BnApx9KZS6bAGGwCJ8ABk7hQQXYZJn8jI1rHMfGZ2x6jhw16ozqA1R0Eux5uYoYL2c7-tArjmjajCMPaBT4F6NaEvw7IwLWRCkGAwgKOgEDQX4SHEpAACeSAAEqBvBIhgCQwwAIwAAz0Qu3jDPRaqLL8-yAsCoLgvBkIwsgcIgAicajuOQmToIACyqj0mmfggPgQiyQyaYqFQlGmC0IzCNR0AALTQLcCBmmBEGNHhBHssQJCYdhyAAOpqAyX4GgYgjgLMICZFwODeGI7EWAMRyCAxbGLGmDKUNCUouhAJHAORmnCJKxiRdFCCCI8KQ8EyT7iSwgrCcgaZKWIggAAYACT0F5qD7NAADi+B9DlIB5ZktXtXlriVeZ6UWGmIpkMA9KCModBiT6xV1KVk1CDVdWZg1mS0IQXX0AtOBpl6UBgGIyB9QNlmMPhRI2RhWHoM5DLuagnkrT5VjcAFay2CgPjDAArEx6ybMMOwREFAq9L63B1OgRDSHq2RZmQsAcBDhh2GBIURGFjFrPQe7PYKyNQ2muNrMqPgQRljJZY+HzEWRFGpWaFMxT1+XSp2MRzWV+AVUt9UgI1LVtblyCbSzx19uBg2sMNqhjRNJrQ2zMqzegabbVVtV841604Jt227UJEAHUd-USxZixJtCqnyRpGBadAOnhaY9z9Mon2qs+7OcJz5Ua8t3mNfdaABWmoemzNSMECjGbwyBFjuJ49pYHZ11CekjDFX0V0OTA0gANqLNTnvKxzqu+zIWSZAAcsgCJEIBRomBLFjZzdLn0m5oogIIFdN4s86F3FhW+iVXMVTIABCmS-QApGwP5BPgtIIBwBmk8KXd9xqrdOe3Qc9xP97QL95kLBYRfDyrpXl+Fc9jaKzLL6v69cgYW+yjvt30vvMiwEfTtmzPqwC+EdvZl25j3W+88H5L3+iqV+qB34yk-nvLuPcAAi-8sZ0l4MgU+jAAC6zhGA7wgApQgWBAjjQminByaxvAYFIEPRYoYPyRmjDQ+y6B6FUFIA7aAAAmRikFzRAA)

Comment: [Code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApQPYFtgGcIDqwYAFgIIBGGUYyEAHpCACa5qY74A8AriANYgMAdxAA+ZAG8AUMmRwqNAFzIAFAEpkAXgkA3DMGbSAvtOkIMIXLQAOcHvm1rZyLLgD8KkDywVoAGhcECk81ADoIuCgAc1wVPkEREABtAF1NHWQEoVFAuQiwqNj4gRyU1Ol1FXRsPEJickVaTJk5ABsIWjBgLAgMHjAvHz8oMzkLK1sOOqcAeQoAKwgEMELcXGBokFUXORAIYXZa-FVVKAhcDDbdCH9kc6WVjIlWuTfu3v7m5HwwABUen0Bqo4LgAJ4gBBqZ5SXZvORgKBg2Hw1H3C5XG4g4RwYjIYLuMKqApFXDqdRw+HGfFwMAIEhqaCYKCaV5ouQPZZgVRM6gU9nIUxo4x3Nz8t7GdR5N5st4KaiDaHaCQIDpRAGfYEfIFgKVwkUuCkuc5gHhQEDIGzTfAmMx2BwQVQARgADG67hplSjkKRMIcAKJQZkaEzqMIIWn004wiaXDphNoYaKqADkEZ40RIYBT5OkQA)

Comment: Thank you so much for your excellent answer! However, I'm still a bit confused, in the above playground, run code would log `caught`, isn't it handling the rejection of the promise returned by `cb`?

Comment: @Leon - I'm not 100% sure what you mean by *"...in the above playground, run code would log `caught`..."*, but you're entirely right that your original `try`/`catch` would catch rejections from `cb`'s promise, I got myself confused there. Sorry about that! I've fixed the answer. That said, using an `async` function and `await` there isn't necessary, you can just resolve your promise to the promise from `cb`. (I've left the `try`/`catch` in the above anyway -- since we don't know what `cb` is, we don't know whether it will throw a synchronous error, return a promise it might reject, etc.) :-)

Comment: Sorry for the vague description, I meant to say in the first comment which contains the `Code` link, run code would log `caught`. And thanks again for your detailed replies.

Comment: @WenfangDu - Wow, I...just plain missed that link, sorry. :-) But the following would be a better example of how the original `try`/`catch` *does* catch rejections (not just synchonrous errors):

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApQPYFtgGcIDqwYAFgIIBGGUYyEAHpCACa5qY74A8AriANYgMAdxAA+ZAG8AUMmRwqNAFzIAFAEpkAXgkA3DMGbSAvtIQYQuWgAc4PfNrWzkWXAH4VIHlgrQANM4IFB5qAHThcFAA5rgqfIIiIADaALqaOsjxQqIBcuGhkTFxAtnJKdLqKujYeITE5Iq0GTJyADYQtGDAWBAYPGCe3r5Q0oEWVsjWHLWOAPIUAFYQCGAFuLjAUSCqznIgEMLsNfiqqlAQuBituhB+yOdLK+kSLXJvXT19Tcj4YAAq3V6-VUcFwAE8QAg1M8pLs3nIwFAwbD4aj7hcrjcQcI4MRkEE3KFVPlCrh1Oo4fDjPi4GAECQ1NBMFBNK80XIHsswKomdQKezkKY0cY7q5+W9jOpcm82W8FNQBtDtBIEO1IgDPsCPkCwFK4SLnBTnOcwDwoCBJtN8CZpLZ7BBVABGAAMrruoIhUI0ypRyFImEOAFEoMyNCZ1KEELT6acYeZLFcIKFWhgoqoAORRnhREhgdPk6RAA